# netlogon event id 5719

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

OS : windows 2008 r2 
after migrate the datastore to the ssd disks, we have an issue with the serevice netlogon.
after reboot the server, The network service is not available when the server tries to open a secure channel with the domain.
The service starts manually without any problem

I wonder if anyone could shed any light on this.

Thanks and advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're describing here. What datastore are you referring to?

Comment: thanks for your reply
the machine windows 2008 R2 it is a vm on the vmware esx version  5.5. 
these files of this vm is located on datastore.

Comment: It would help if you could supply error messages related to this issue from the VMware host and/or from the Windows 2008 R2 server (event logs). Do some services fail to start (eventlog?). Any additional information might help to pinpoint you issue. Please elaborate.